# PowerBI Measure grab a value from STARTOFMONTH?

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a monthly forecast QTY that I'd like spread out into days for the purpose of a line chart.

I have a date table which is broken out into days. As for my forecasts table, it is structured with:

- Month (in M/1/YYYY format)
- QTY

So my hope was doing something like:

```
Daily FCST = 
DIVIDE(
    CALCULATE(
      SUMX(Forecasts, Forecasts[Month] = STARTOFMONTH(Dates[Date])), 
      Forecasts[QTY]
    ),
    DAY(CALCULATE(EOMONTH(LASTDATE(Dates[Date]),0)))
)
```

This NEARLY works, however it only returns a value for the 1st of the month. Other days of the month are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution!

The trick was that I needed to use the DATEADD function in order to shift my date table backwards by a different number of days, each day day.

In the below code, the `shiftedDates` variable is a date table that's shifted backwards X number of days, where X is the day of the month - 1. So for example if the date we're checking is the 17th, then `shiftedDates` will have been shifted backwards 16 days. Thus causing the 17th to align to the 1st.

```
Daily FCST =

var dateToCalculate = CALCULATE(FIRSTDATE(Dates[Date]))
var shiftedDates = DATEADD(Dates[Date], -(DAY(dateToCalculate)-1), DAY)
var numOfDays = DAY(EOMONTH(Dates[Date])

return DIVIDE(CALCULATE(SUM(Forecasts[QTY]), shiftedDates), numOfDays)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to spread the monthly amount over the days in the month, why not just get a count of days in the month in the current evaluation context and divide by that? You may have to relax the evaluation context so that you get all the days in the month and then get a count. Something along the lines of COUNTROWS(FILTER(ALL('Calendar'),'Calendar'[MonthNo]= MAX('Calendar'[MonthNo]) && 'Calendar'[Year] = MAX('Calendar'[Year])))

Basically, remove the day filter form the current context, but keep the Month and the Year. (Maybe I should be using KEEPFILTERS?)

Comment: Thanks for your input. My challenge isn't the division by number of days. Specifically, my challenge is just with the `CALCULATE(SUMX())` portion. My `Forecast[Month]` column only has data for the 1st of each month, so my hope was that `STARTOFMONTH()` would floor my input date to the start of the month, so that every day would return a value. In other words, even if I remove the `DIVIDE()` part of my measure, I am currently being returned 100% of the monthly value on the 1st, and each other day is null.